# Cell Shading Visible Only When Printed? Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: ms-word, formatting, cell, shading

I have a bunch of Word documents with tables in them. I was using Windows XP and Office 2007 when I created them. Within the documents, I often use cell shading (the little tilted bucket) to shade certain cells for them to stand out. I upgraded to Office 2010 and all of the documents continued to be fine.

We recently upgraded to Windows 7 which had Office 2010 in it. I'm reading everywhere that no version of Windows 7 comes with Office but this is at my job and whatever image they're using to upgrade all the computers to Windows 7 already has Office 2010 on it so I don't know.

Anyway, since the upgrade, the original cell shading of my documents isn't visible to me anymore. At first, I thought it had completely disappeared because it looks as if nothing is there but when I print the documents, they print with the shading as if nothing is wrong.

If I apply new cell shading, I can see THAT on the screen, but the original shading is "hidden" or something. Anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: This question really doesn't belong on a programming site, you should find some Office support.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I find out that it has something to do with the way Office was programmed with installation that caused the colors to shift. Lowering the contrast of the monitor and the brightness restored the appearance of the cell shading, which in the current installation was thrown shades off from the original to the point of being invisible.